# Why is the regex not matching a method with null parameter?

Tags: regex

I have the following regex which matches a function "searchresult" whose third parameter is "null" or "string.Empty":

```
^(.*\.)?searchresult\((?:[^,]*,){2}\s*(null|string\.Empty)\s*(?:,[^,]*){2}\);
```

The regex should NOT match the below lines

```
errorList.Add(new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.searchresult("[Validation_MaxLength_ErrorMessage_2000]", staffonlineInquiry, "onlineInquiryResponseInformation", string.Empty, null));
searchresult error = new searchresult("[Validation_notwellLeavecheckReturnToWorkDateYes_ErrorMessage]|[Label_IsnotwellLeavecheckReturnToWorkDate_Text]", target, "notwellLeavecheckReturnToWorkDate", null, null);
```

The regex should match the following lines

```
errorList.Add(new Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.searchresult("[Validation_MaxLength_ErrorMessage_2000]", enquiry, null, string.Empty, null));
searchresult error = new searchresult("[Validation_notwellLeavecheckReturnToWorkDateYes_ErrorMessage]|[Label_IsnotwellLeavecheckReturnToWorkDate_Text]", target, string.Empty, null, null);
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to actually ask a question at the end of your question. Is the problem that the expression is erroneously matching the first set of lines?

Comment: Your reges does't match first set of lines - it's OK.
Your regex matches 1st line of the second set, but not 2nd line. Look at [test1](https://regex101.com/r/CUXj1f/1).
It's because of ````\.```` at the beginning - it allows only ````.searchresult````. Without dot, it [looks fine](https://regex101.com/r/CUXj1f/2) (but, I'm not sure of other uses of your "searchresult" function and its parameters, afraid of possible other discrepancies).